# How do I serve an express + vue app on same domain in Heroku

Tags: vue.js, express, heroku

I have a backend api in express and a front end in vue.js with typescript.

In my development environment, the front end talks to the backend via a proxy server defined in the vue.config.js file...

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "^/api": {
        target: 'http://localhost:3002',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {"^/api": "/"} 
      },
    }
  }
}
```

**So, my front end expects to be served on [address] and it is expecting the express application to be at [address]/api on the SAME address/url.**

I was able to achieve this on Digital Ocean App Platform by setting up 2 'components', a backend served from '/api' and a front end component with the Vue.js stuff in it served from '/' on the same domain.

**How can I achieve this in Heroku?**

I have seen a lot of people (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-b9KGwVECs) suggest using a build step that builds the front end, copies the static assets back up into a 'public' folder and then uses express to serve the static assets as well as the rest api using this...

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
```

But is this really the best way to do it?  Seems to me like now Express is responsible for the front end and the backend when they should be seperate concerns.  Also, what about scaling the back vs the front?, does this work for CDNs?

This seems like such a common use case for something like Heroku, maybe I am just missing something obvious.